# flutter: how to make list from mysql-data?

Tags: mysql, json, list, flutter

From the MySQL query I get data like this:

```
(Fields: {IDAufgaben: 2630, Aufgabe: erste Aufgabe}, 
 Fields: {IDAufgaben: 2627, Aufgabe: Testen})
```

`json.decode` gives a `FormatException` — I think because the quotes are lacking.

How can I change the MySQL data received in a Dart list?

Thanks a lot for help, I am newbie in Flutter and Dart…

Comment: Can you control the data so it's proper JSON?  It actually might already be YAML too.

Answer (score 0):

should quote marks too, but if you take it from the terminallog then what happens is the quotation tent is not included, the solution is to change to json using jsonencode

like this one :

```dart
final myfiled = {"IDAufgaben": "2630", "Aufgabe": "erste Aufgabe"};
print(JsonEncoder.withIndent(" ").convert(myfiled));

/// result terminal is :

{
 "IDAufgaben": "2630",
 "Aufgabe": "erste Aufgabe"
}
```

Comment: thanks, malik, but this didn't work. I finally produced a webpage on the database server wwhich produces a correct json file.